# Java hadoop api YarnClient doesn't have "init()/start()" function?

Tags: java, api, hadoop, client, hadoop-yarn

I tried maven repo like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then my java code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationConstants;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClientApplication;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    YarnConfiguration yarnConfiguration = new YarnConfiguration();
    YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
    yarnClient.init(yarnConfiguration);
    yarnClient.start();
}
```

Intellij ide shows "Cannot solve method init" and "Cannot solve method start".

I then tried to use jar version of 3.1.1 instead of "2.7.2". Same result. So what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

the init and start method are derived from the AbstractService class.
you need to verify the YarnClient and AbstractService has the same version.

go to YarnClient and check the jar it refer to, then click on the AbstractService parent from the Yarn client and check his version.

change the YarnClient version according to your AbstractService version.

i had the same issue, it works for me . version 2.6.5 .